# Mutually exclusive checkboxes which are styled with :before and :after CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Long time reader, first time poster here.

I am using checkboxes that have been styled as ON/OFF switches from http://proto.io/freebies/

This has worked very well for situations where the "checkbox" is appropriate. But, I have now run into a situation where I need "radio" like functionality (mutually exclusive).

I have found some Jquery solutions for making mutually exclusive checkboxes, but they do not accommodate the :before and :after CSS styling of the Proto.io switch.

How can I make the styled checkboxes within a div class="checkrow" mutually exclusive?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zLGnu/2/

```
<div class="checkrow">
<div class="w-col w-col-3">
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="instagram">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="instagram">
            <div class="onoffswitch-inner-instagram"></div>
            <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="w-col w-col-3">
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="twitter">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="twitter">
            <div class="onoffswitch-inner-twitter"></div>
            <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.onoffswitch-label').click(function () {
        $(".onoffswitch-checkbox").parent().removeClass('onoffswitch-checked');
        $(this).parent().addClass('onoffswitch-checked');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLGnu/3/

Note: change the `type="radio"` in inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That does work, but it is not quite what I am looking for. I need the switches to be able to be grouped and mutually exclusive of just those switches in the same group.

Comment: My sample is mutually exclusive. and if you want to group, http://jsfiddle.net/zLGnu/5/ you can give any group name.

Comment: I ended up going with this: http://jsfiddle.net/zLGnu/8/       Although I know very little about object oriented programming, this seemed more object oriented because it is easier to apply across many situations without have to name the groups or write a new function per group.   Thanks for your help, it is very much appreciated!